# Summability Condition for Linear Process

Tags: statistics, variance, time-series

I have been studying linear processes in time series of the following form:

$X_t= \sum_{j=0}^{\infty}c_j\epsilon_{t-j}$

In this case, the following implication (about the covariance function) holds:

$ \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} j|c_i| < \infty \Rightarrow \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} j|\gamma_i|   < \infty $

However, I have some trouble understanding the proof which runs us follows:

$ \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} j^p|\gamma_i| \leq \sigma^2 \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} |c_i|\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} j^p|c_{i+j}| \leq  \sigma^2 \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} |c_i|\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} (i+j)^p |c_{i+j}| \leq \sigma^2 \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} |c_i|\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} j^p |c_{j}| < \infty$

I do not understand the following part (the last inequality):

$ \sigma^2 \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} |c_i|\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} (i+j)^p |c_{i+j}| \leq \sigma^2 \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} |c_i|\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} j^p |c_{j}| < \infty$

Can anyone please help me out and explain why it holds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a fixed $i$, the substitution $k=i+j$ gives
$$\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} (i+j)^p |c_{i+j}|=\sum_{k=i}^\infty k^p\left\lvert c_k\right\rvert\leqslant \sum_{k=0}^\infty k^p\left\lvert c_k\right\rvert.$$

Comment: I thought about this too, and its probably a misunderstanding from my part, but why is $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} k^p |c_k| = \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} j^p |c_j| $, since for any $ i>0, k \neq j$?

Comment: The summation variable does not matter, you can write this as $\sum_{\ell=0}^\infty \ell^p\lvert c_\ell\rvert$ if you want.

Comment: Ah yes. Thank you!